# NoClassDefFoundError running TestNG test jar

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, classpath

Currently I have a TestNG/Selenium/Maven/Java project that I have setup to run as a jar with a goal of **test-jar**.  I used the maven dependency plugin to essentially copy all the dependencies to a lib folder in the test-classes folder within target directory.  My manifest in the JAR has the Class-Path with all jars.  When I run a java -jar myjar-tests.jar I get a NoClassDefFoundError as seenb elow:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestListenerAdapter
        at runner.CrystalUIMain.main(CrystalUIMain.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestListenerAdapter
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 1 more
```

Below is my pom.xml (maven dependency plugin and goal as test-jar for maven jar plugin):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.crystalfw</groupId>
    <artifactId>ui</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ui</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.2gis.winium</groupId>
            <artifactId>winium-webdriver</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0-1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-http-jdk-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
<!--            <classifier>no_aop</classifier>-->
<!--            <scope>compile</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.48</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.0.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
<!--                                <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>-->
                                <manifest>
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                </manifest>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>runner.CrystalUIMain</Main-Class>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Below is my main class:

```
package runner;

import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.collections.Lists;

import java.util.List;

public class CrystalUIMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
        suites.add("testng_basic.xml");//path to xml..
        testng.setTestSuites(suites);
        testng.run();
    }
}
```

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.3.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 17
Class-Path: testng-7.8.0.jar jquery-3.6.1.jar selenium-java-4.9.0.jar se
 lenium-api-4.9.0.jar selenium-chrome-driver-4.9.0.jar selenium-chromium
 -driver-4.9.0.jar selenium-json-4.9.0.jar selenium-manager-4.9.0.jar se
 lenium-devtools-v110-4.9.0.jar selenium-devtools-v111-4.9.0.jar seleniu
 m-devtools-v112-4.9.0.jar selenium-devtools-v85-4.9.0.jar selenium-edge
 -driver-4.9.0.jar selenium-firefox-driver-4.9.0.jar selenium-ie-driver-
 4.9.0.jar selenium-remote-driver-4.9.0.jar netty-buffer-4.1.91.Final.ja
 r netty-codec-http-4.1.91.Final.jar netty-codec-4.1.91.Final.jar netty-
 handler-4.1.91.Final.jar netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar netty-transport-
 classes-epoll-4.1.91.Final.jar netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.91.Fi
 nal.jar netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.91.Final.jar netty-trans
 port-4.1.91.Final.jar netty-resolver-4.1.91.Final.jar opentelemetry-api
 -1.25.0.jar opentelemetry-context-1.25.0.jar opentelemetry-exporter-log
 ging-1.25.0.jar opentelemetry-sdk-metrics-1.25.0.jar opentelemetry-sdk-
 logs-1.25.0-alpha.jar opentelemetry-api-logs-1.25.0-alpha.jar opentelem
 etry-api-events-1.25.0-alpha.jar opentelemetry-sdk-common-1.25.0.jar op
 entelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi-1.25.0.jar opentelemetry-sd
 k-extension-autoconfigure-1.25.0-alpha.jar opentelemetry-sdk-trace-1.25
 .0.jar opentelemetry-sdk-1.25.0.jar opentelemetry-semconv-1.25.0-alpha.
 jar jtoml-2.0.0.jar byte-buddy-1.14.4.jar commons-exec-1.3.jar async-ht
 tp-client-2.12.3.jar async-http-client-netty-utils-2.12.3.jar netty-cod
 ec-socks-4.1.60.Final.jar netty-handler-proxy-4.1.60.Final.jar netty-tr
 ansport-native-epoll-4.1.60.Final-linux-x86_64.jar netty-transport-nati
 ve-kqueue-4.1.60.Final-osx-x86_64.jar netty-reactive-streams-2.0.4.jar 
 jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar selenium-safari-driver-4.9.0.jar selenium-
 support-4.9.0.jar extentreports-5.0.9.jar rxjava-3.0.4.jar reactive-str
 eams-1.0.3.jar freemarker-2.3.30.jar gson-2.8.6.jar lombok-1.18.24.jar 
 poi-ooxml-5.2.2.jar poi-5.2.2.jar commons-codec-1.15.jar commons-math3-
 3.6.1.jar SparseBitSet-1.2.jar poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.2.jar xmlbeans-5.0.3.
 jar commons-compress-1.21.jar commons-io-2.11.0.jar curvesapi-1.07.jar 
 commons-collections4-4.4.jar webdrivermanager-5.3.2.jar docker-java-3.2
 .14.jar docker-java-core-3.2.14.jar docker-java-api-3.2.14.jar jackson-
 annotations-2.10.3.jar jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar jackson-core-2.10.3.
 jar bcpkix-jdk15on-1.64.jar bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.
 30.jar docker-java-transport-httpclient5-3.2.14.jar docker-java-transpo
 rt-3.2.14.jar jna-5.12.1.jar dec-0.1.2.jar commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar htt
 pclient5-5.2.1.jar httpcore5-5.2.jar httpcore5-h2-5.2.jar winium-webdri
 ver-0.1.0-1.jar postgresql-42.5.0.jar checker-qual-3.5.0.jar slf4j-api-
 2.0.6.jar log4j-core-2.20.0.jar log4j-api-2.20.0.jar selenium-http-jdk-
 client-4.8.1.jar auto-service-annotations-1.0.1.jar auto-service-1.0.1.
 jar auto-common-1.2.jar selenium-http-4.8.1.jar failsafe-3.3.0.jar rest
 -assured-5.3.0.jar groovy-4.0.6.jar groovy-xml-4.0.6.jar httpclient-4.5
 .13.jar httpcore-4.4.13.jar commons-logging-1.2.jar httpmime-4.5.13.jar
  hamcrest-2.1.jar tagsoup-1.2.1.jar json-path-5.3.0.jar groovy-json-4.0
 .6.jar rest-assured-common-5.3.0.jar xml-path-5.3.0.jar json-simple-1.1
 .1.jar junit-4.10.jar hamcrest-core-1.1.jar guice-4.1.0.jar javax.injec
 t-1.jar aopalliance-1.0.jar jcommander-1.48.jar guava-32.0.1-jre.jar fa
 ilureaccess-1.0.1.jar listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-w
 ith-guava.jar jsr305-3.0.2.jar error_prone_annotations-2.18.0.jar j2obj
 c-annotations-2.8.jar
Main-Class: runner.CrystalUIMain
```

Any suggestions as to why I am getting this error even with the manifest classpath having all the jars?